# AppleScript Hash Symbol (#) in URL

Tags: javascript, macos, applescript, translation

I have this Automator AppleScript to translate texts. It works, but only with one word. If I select two words or more to translate, it changes the hash (#) in the URL to %23, like this

https://www.deepl.com/translator%23pt/en/

and I get a 404 Not Found.

```
on run {input, parameters}
    open location "https://www.deepl.com/translator#pt/en/" & input
end run
```

Comment: `input` is a `list` and needs to be flattened to a `string/text` and properly **URL encoded**.

Comment: @user3439894 Fantastic! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use '**Listing 32-7** AppleScriptObjC: Handler that URL encodes text' from [Encoding and Decoding Text](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/EncodeandDecodeText.html).

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
use framework "Foundation"
use scripting additions

on run {input, parameters}
    open location "https://www.deepl.com/translator#pt/en/" & encodeText(input as string)
end run

on encodeText(theText)
    set theString to stringWithString_(theText) of NSString of current application
    set theEncoding to NSUTF8StringEncoding of current application
    set theAdjustedString to stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding_(theEncoding) of theString
    return (theAdjustedString as string)
end encodeText
```

Comment: Fantastic!
Thank you very much!